# Pack a date into an int variable (Java)

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a problem that asks from me to pack and unpack a calendaristic date in an **int variable**. For example, *20th February 2007* will be represented as folows:

- first **5 bits** will be reserved for the day
- the next **4 bits**
  will be reserved for the month
- the **last bits** will be reserved for the    year

Unfortunately, this is all the information I have. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do what you described, it sounds fine. What's the problem?

Comment: @Braj, it returns a long.. then you want to cast into int ? Do you think its wise ?

Comment: `int intDate = day | (month << 5) | (year << (4 + 5));`.

Comment: Base 2 log of x can be computed as log(x)/log(2). Day: log(31)/log(2) ~= 4.954, so need 5 bits for day; Month: log(12)/log(2) ~= 3.585, so need 4 bits for month; but log(2048)/log(2) = 11, so 10 bits for month will only do for a "few" years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the sequence as per your requirement.

Its simple use of `String#substring()` and `Integer#toBinaryString()`.

```
int date = 20;
int month = 2;
int year = 2007;
String d = String.format("%0$5s", Integer.toBinaryString(date));
String m = String.format("%0$4s", Integer.toBinaryString(month));
String y = String.format("%0$23s", Integer.toBinaryString(year));

String str = y + m + d;
str = str.replace(' ', '0');
System.out.println(str);
int number = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    number = (number << 1) | ((str.charAt(i) != '0') ? 1 : 0);
}
System.out.println(number);
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(number));
```

get the date back from returned number

```
String str1=String.format("%0$32s", Integer.toBinaryString(number)).replace(' ', '0');
int originalYear= Integer.parseInt(str1.substring(0,23), 2);
int originalMonth= Integer.parseInt(str1.substring(23,27), 2);
int originalDate= Integer.parseInt(str1.substring(27,32), 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using a 32 bit signed integer and you ignore the sign bit and that by "calendaristic" you mean that it is of the type Calendar then the following method should do the trick:

```
public static int calToInt(Calendar cal) {
    int date = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) << 26;
    date |= cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) << 22;
    date |= cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    return date;
}
```

Note that in the implementation of Calendar, January is 0, if you want January to be represented by 1, then ensure that you add 1 to the month. Also note that based on my assumptions, your year has 22 bits to work with so will work until the year that is `2^22` i.e the year 4194304, which should be more than sufficient.

**Explanation**

You may not be interested in the rest but I like to explain how things work even if I only provide a rough overview:

The way this works is by taking the calendar object, getting the day and shifting it 26 bits to the left (that's what the `<< 26` does) which would mean that with day of month being a maximum of 5 bits, the day will actually start on the second bit of a 32bit int. This is to avoid the first bit which represents if the int is negative. If you wish to fill the full int then change 22 to 23 and 26 to 27 which will give you a bit extra for your year (double in fact). Likewise with the month of the year, it is shifted 22 bits to the left so that it comes after the day of month with a maximum consumption of 4 bits.

The `|=` operator is a bitwise or assignment operator. What this does is do a bitwise or of the thing on the left, with the thing on the right and assign to the thing on the left. You can do this in one line, but this is much clearer in my opinion and in terms of byte code will result in the same thing. What is meant by OR is that if either bit from either the left or right is a 1 then the output will contain a 1 in that position. This is how the individual parts are put together.

If the year did happen to be larger than the stated max, it would mess things up.

**To Reverse:**

In order to get this int back into a Calendar object the following method can be used:

```
private static Calendar intToCal(int date) {
    int day = date >> 26;
    int month = (date & 0b00000011110000000000000000000000) >> 22;
    int year = date & 0b00000000001111111111111111111111;
    return new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
}
```

This works using bitmasks and bit shifting. So the first one just shifts 26 bits along (all other bits to the right get lost and we are left with the day.
With the month and day bitmasks are used. I have written these in binary format to make it clearer exactly what it does. I am using a logical and to get only the bits from the int that I want. in the month, only the bits marked with a 1 in the bitmask will be left (this removes the day of month before we shift). I have also gotten rid of the bits on the right of the month but this is not required and will be cut off like they were in the first when the right bit shift is performed. The year just needs the mask as those last 22 bits are just simply the year in binary form. Again, I have ignored the sign bit however this is not explicit in the first and if a negative was passed it would mess this up. To fix this a mask must be applied to the day to mask the sign bit.

Comment: You are setting the last 5 bits to be the day, the previous 4 to be the month and the first ones to be the year. That makes little sense.

Comment: I have just finished adding my description of what I have done. Also it depends how you look at the int, and possibly whether you are using little or big endian. The concept is correct, and I have made it do that visually from left to right it fits what was asked for.

Comment: +1 for the use of bitwise operators (`<<` and `|=`).

Comment: One last thing. I understood what you have done, but I cannot figure a simple way to unpack it? From int to get a date. Should I transform it in a array of bits?

Comment: I have added a reversing method. Obviously you loose the time from the original Calendar but it does what it needs to do.